# Having trouble getting Axios.post to send my form-data

Tags: php, ajax, vuejs2, upload, axios

This is my first post here though I read it all the time, so please correct me in all the various ways I'm probably not asking this correctly. I'm building a vue application that will send images to a folder on my server. In order to do this, I am trying to use Axios.post to send my formData to my PHP file for processing. I've tested that the permissions in php.ini are working (they are, I have an alternate version of the same post that uses raw php without an ajax request and it works fine but loads in a new window which I'm trying to avoid).

Here's what I think is relevant.

Vue component

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

Vue.component('uploader1', {
 props:['yo'],
 template:
 `<div>
   <label>
    <div class="cButton">Artwork Image(1)</div>
    <input class="hiddenInput" id="file" type="file" ref="file" @change="onFileChanged">
   </label>
    <div class="cButton" @click="onUpload">Upload</div>
  </div>`,
 data(){
  return{selectedFile: null}
 },
 methods:{
  onFileChanged (event) {
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0]
  },
 onUpload() {
  const formData = new FormData()
  // formData.append('myFile', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name)
  // console.log(this.selectedFile)
  // console.log(formData.get('myFile'))
  axios.post('http://asagiannini.com/crit/axios_upload.php', formData, {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
          }).then(function(data){
              console.log(data.data);
            })
            .catch(function(){
              console.log('FAILURE!!');
            });
},
 },
})
```

I have confirmed that the formdata appending is working. I have confirmed that Axios is loading correctly. I have confirmed that my server supports file uploading, but I have no idea why, when I echo $_FILES in my php, it comes up as an empty array.

Comment: Is your last version of code? Why you commented out `formData.append`?

Comment: Sorry, those are commented out from something I was trying to fix the issue. In reality they should not be.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it turns out my issue was that I had a typo in my php file. Sorry about that.